# PHP 7.1 work in CLI but apache not executing

Tags: php, apache

PHP 7.1 works in CLI in Ubuntu 16 but Apache not executing PHP. Info.php is displayed as blank screen. Any guidance?

Comment: Has PHP been installed for the web server?

Comment: Is the php module loaded in the apache? What does the log files say?

Comment: Yes. PHP installed and command line PHP -V displays full description of installed version. How to load php 7.1 in apache? Log has nothing much.